# How to run a background process in Android repeatedly

Tags: android, timer, process, background

I am using `AlarmManager` for repeated background process. My app repeatedly requests data from server in 5 sec interval. But after some long time, when I open my app it crashes. I can't figure out why.

How should I execute a background process repeatedly? Should I use AlarmManager`,`Timer` or something else?

My background process should run always even when the app does not have focus or isn't active.

Comment: `AlarmManager` is definitely ok. Another way of getting fresh data from server is `PUSH` notifications.

Comment: If you have a crash, you should post a stack trace from logcat. If you want to do work while the app is not visible to the user, you should be using a `Service`.

Comment: I just search found AlarmManager code in internet and implement it. Have no idea which is best. @blackbelt

Comment: Can you give me some good resource for PUSH notifications @Fox in socks

Comment: How i use service for repeated background process? @Karakuri

Comment: @yousuf android docs have an extensive tutorial on how to set up push notifications. its very simple and very easy. just google it. it'll be one of the first results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My app repeatedly request server for data 5 sec interval.

Users with mobile devices, like phones and tablets, will not appreciate your behavior. They will not appreciate your consumption of battery life and your consumption of bandwidth. Device manufacturers and Google are continuing to take aggressive steps to prevent applications like yours from behaving this way, both automatically and by giving users the tools to find ill-behaving apps like yours and get rid of them.

> But After some long time when i open my app its crash

Most likely, you have a bug in your app. You will need to fix the bug. Since you have provided no details of your crash, such as source code and a stack trace, nobody can really help you with that.

> Which is the best for repeated background process, AlarmManager, Timer or something else?

Switch to a user-configurable and less-crazy polling period (e.g., every 15 minutes by default), then use `AlarmManager` in conjunction with an `IntentService`, so that your process can cleanly go away

Or, switch to having the server send messages to the device when the data of interest changes, such as via [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). This will allow you to drop the polling period to something infrequent (e.g., every hour by default), as a fallback mechanism in case you miss a push message for some reason.

> My background process should run always though the app is not on focus or active

Your users will disagree with you. They do not want apps running all of the time, tying up system RAM. They *really* do not want apps that consume battery and bandwidth the way that you are proposing. The users will get rid of your background process, either by:

- swiping your app off the recent-tasks list
- using a third-party task manager
- force-stopping your app via its entry in the application list in Settings
- uninstalling your app